# How to make canvas transparent in Android?

Tags: android, xml, canvas, background, transparent

I want to make the drawing surface of my app transparent so that the my app can look like the user can draw on top of my background image, I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
>

    <com.almondmendoza.drawings.DrawingSurface
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:id="@+id/drawingSurface"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/colorGreenBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Scratch"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/colorRedBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Minor Scratch"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/colorBlueBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/dentBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Minor Dent"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/minorDentBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Damaged"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/damagedBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Undo"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/undoBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Redo"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/redoBtn" />
        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/saveBtn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ouput of the XML code above is like this:

[image]

As you can see the drawing surface is the black part of the screen. I want this to be transparent, is that possible?

Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.logistics.kiddiekuts.Trans;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TransparentPanel extends RelativeLayout {
    private Paint innerPaint, borderPaint;

    public TransparentPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        innerPaint = new Paint();
        innerPaint.setARGB(225, 225, 225, 225); // gray
        innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    }

    public void setInnerPaint(Paint innerPaint) {
        this.innerPaint = innerPaint;
    }

    public void setBorderPaint(Paint borderPaint) {
        this.borderPaint = borderPaint;
    }

    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        RectF drawRect = new RectF();
        drawRect.set(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 8, 8, innerPaint);
        // canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, borderPaint);

        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

XML::

```
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name :" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="27dip"
                    android:id="@+id/tvname" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                <EditText android:layout_width="197dip" android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dip" android:textSize="12dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="23dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvname"
                    android:layout_height="35dip" />

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Phone :" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="18dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvname" android:id="@+id/tvphone"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                <EditText android:layout_width="197dip" android:id="@+id/phone"
                    android:textSize="12dip" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvphone"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name" android:layout_height="35dip"></EditText>

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Email :" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvphone" android:id="@+id/tvemail"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                <EditText android:layout_width="197dip" android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:textSize="12dip" android:layout_marginLeft="9dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvemail"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/phone" android:layout_height="35dip"></EditText>


                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Category :" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvemail" android:id="@+id/tvcategory"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/category"
                    android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="For Appointment" android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvcategory" android:layout_below="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Location :" android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvcategory" android:id="@+id/tvlocation"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtlocation"
                    android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Atlanta,Ga"  android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvlocation" android:layout_below="@+id/category"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>


                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Message:"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvlocation" android:id="@+id/tvatn"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <EditText android:layout_width="250dip" android:id="@+id/atn"
                    android:textSize="12dip" android:lines="7" android:layout_below="@+id/tvatn"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:gravity="top|left" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
                <Button android:layout_height="25dip" android:layout_below="@+id/atn"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:id="@+id/btnsubmit" android:background="@drawable/submit_btn"


                    android:layout_width="250dip"></Button>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnsubmit" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            </com.logistics.kiddiekuts.Trans.TransparentPanel>
```

Comment: @have any idea i am working on  app letter drawing practise in which number shown on letter like letter D having two part 1) is vertical line and 2) is Arc so in that first number are shown in first part and draw only on that part if user move outside the part than reload view as completed first part the number shown on second part and draw only on it and need somthing is suppose in first part num 1 2 3 are shown and user move upto 1 than remove that and so on and also avoid redrawing too .. i am stucking since few days any helps appreciated

Comment: my question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731196/alphabet-drawing-practice-in-android

Comment: @ khan did you got solution for this ?