# How we can make user to practice alphabet on canvas in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing a application where i want, user can practice the English alphabets,clicking on "Practice" button.I got a reference here but this code is not working. I am new to android.Can anyone help me with code,how I can do this.

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetricsInt;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class AlphaDraw extends View {

   public interface AlphaScrollable {
      public void scrollAlpha(char prefix);
   }

   public AlphaScrollable target;

   public AlphaDraw(Context context) {
      super(context);
   }

   public AlphaDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
   }

   public AlphaDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   protected String[] alpha = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

   protected boolean touching = false;

   // try capturing touches to jump to letters
   // will actively adjust list location
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

      float margin = this.getWidth() / 4;
      float fracy = (event.getY() - (margin * 2)) / (this.getHeight() - (margin * 4));

      int approx = (int) (alpha.length * fracy);
      // Log.d("ALPHA", String.format("approx=%s", alpha[approx]));

      if (approx < 0 || approx >= alpha.length)
         return true;

      // jump to alpha location in list

      // find first letter location in list
      this.target.scrollAlpha(alpha[approx].charAt(0));

      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         this.touching = true;
         this.invalidate();
         break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         this.touching = false;
         this.invalidate();
         break;

      }

      return true;

   }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      // show shadow only when being actively touched

      float width = this.getWidth(), height = this.getHeight();
      float margin = this.getWidth() / 4;

      float spacing = (height - (margin * 4)) / alpha.length;

      int shadowColor = Color.argb(128, 0, 0, 0);
      GradientDrawable shadow = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] { shadowColor, shadowColor });
      shadow.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
      shadow.setCornerRadius(10);

      shadow.setBounds((int) margin, (int) margin, (int) (width - margin), (int) (height - margin));

      if (touching)
         shadow.draw(canvas);

      // draw alphabet index
      // remember that text is drawn from bottom

      Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
      paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
      paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

      // measure to figure out perfect text height
      // W is a nice average letter
      // read new metrics to get exact pixel dimensions
      FontMetricsInt fm = paint.getFontMetricsInt();
      // float charHeight = Math.abs(fm.top) + Math.abs(fm.descent);
      float startTop = (margin * 2) + Math.abs(fm.top);

      for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
         float charWidth = paint.measureText(alpha[i]);
         float centered = (width - charWidth) / 2;

         canvas.drawText(alpha[i], centered, (i * spacing) + startTop, paint);

      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Deva: This code is not working. Now I want to create a activity that would display the alphabet, draw a transparent canvas on that and user can draw on top of that canvas seeing through transparent film over the activity. Can you help me doing code for this or any reference so that i can proceed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best would be to create a activity that would display the alphabet 
draw a transparent canvas on that and let user draw on top of that canvas 
seeing through transparent film over the activity

Comment: let me know if you need help on that

Comment: Yes sure Aashish. I too thought the same logic but i dont know how to proceed as I am new to android. Can you help me in code or any reference so that I can proceed.

Comment: can you create a activity which display Alphabets ??? I will help you with canvas

Comment: https://rapidshare.com/files/159873389/Testing_Images.rar     this is link to my project I am sure you will find it very useful use fingerpaint class in your project

Comment: Thanks its working.Okay I will try to create a activity which display alphabet.But i want my canvas should be able write above the alphabet but not on the either sides. how to do that??

Comment: fix the size of drawing area to the characters you display

Comment: Go to this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484352/how-to-make-canvas-transparent-in-android. I think it may solve your problem, as I am not so good in implementation. Now can you send me edited code which will satisfy my requirement??

Comment: @Delwin Asshish have any idea i am working on same app letter drawing practise in which number shown on letter like letter D having two part 1) is vertical line and 2) is Arc so in that first number are shown in first part and draw only on that part if user move outside the part than reload view as completed first part the number shown on second part and draw only on it and need somthing is suppose in first part num 1 2 3 are shown and user move upto 1 than remove that and so on and also avoid redrawing too ..   i am stucking since few days any helps appreciated

Comment: @AashishVirendraKBhatnagar
Sir,i am also want to implement this(Practising alphabates)
I am trying to get project from "rapidshare.com/files/159873389/Testing_Images.rar " this link.
But it telling me no file available.
Plz help me sir

Comment: @Aashish Bhatnagar can you share your code again? Above link is not working. I need help.